# Error when generating scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I use RVM with ruby 1.9.2 and Rails. When I try to generate a scaffold for my Rails app, I get this error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from script/generate:2:in `<main>'
```

Is there something wrong with rubygems? RVM?

Comment: Are you generating your scaffold from the Rails root?

Comment: Yes (well, at least I believe so). I ran this after opening a fresh terminal.

Comment: Also, not sure if this matters but when i run 'which gem' I get this output: /home/connor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/gem

Comment: I'm getting the same error mate.  Any help would be great as I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I did find if you run the same command but with './script/generate' instead of 'script/generate' you get a different exception.  Doesn't fix it but I wonder why the exception is different.

Comment: Which version of ruby and which version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the root of your rails application, not just wherever you happen to be when you open your terminal.

E.g. if you ran "rails new foo", that will create a directory called "foo" which contains all the files for your application.  You need to be in the directory "foo" whenever you run a rails generator.

Comment: Okay, just used cd to get to the app's root. Got the same error. I'm using Rails 2.3.2 by the way. Does this make it more clear what may be wrong?

Comment: Could you give us the exact command you are typing.  It's rather hard to see what might be wrong if all we have is the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed the problem I was experiencing.

Basically, I was using ruby version 1.9.2 and rails version 2.2.2.  I was only using this version of rails because I am following a rails book and wanted to use the same version that it's examples were written in.

Anyway, when I use ruby version 1.8.7 it seems to work fine.  I also tried using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.3 and it all works fine too.

So, I think your problem may be a conflict between the version of ruby and rails that you're using.

So, in summary, to fix the problem above I changed my version of ruby to 1.8.7 while using rails 2.2.2